# box colliders next to each other bug

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, collider

I work on a game in which you can build your own level and play it. You can create a cube, with a box collider, and move it where you wants. You can also change its color. But when you put two cube next to the other, the character will detect a collision on Z axis. As my character collider is a capsule, it make my character jump. If I put a box collider instead of capsule, my character is stopped.

Here is a explanatory video: https://youtu.be/xuqs1zcdDlk

I tried to overlap both colliders, but problem is still here. Colliders have exactly the same height. How should I solve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Edit > Project Settings > Physics`, and try your game changing the `Default Contact Offset` value untill 0.

Good luck for your game, can't wait to play it !

Comment: It works ! Thanks, i'll give to you a free beta access ;)